# Number of valid sub-string algorithm

Tags: c, string, algorithm, substring

I came across a question for which I couldn't find the algorithm. Can you help me?
Question- A valid substring is one which contains the letter `a` or `z`. You will get a string and you have to calculate the number of valid sub-strings of that string.For example- the string '`abcd`' contains 4 valid substrings. The string '`azazaz`' contains 21 valid substrings and similarly '`abbzbba`' contains 22 valid substrings.
I just want to know the algorithm.

Comment: Why not find all the possibe substrings and check if it fits the asked criterion ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! **We are not a code writing service.** Please show us what you have tried, and detail what the problem is. Also, learn [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) good questions for more tips.

Comment: @Akira The question is asking for an algorithm/pseudo-code, which is fine. That someone still decided to post the full C code is no fault of the OP.

Comment: @Lundin, in this case, I seem to misunderstand the OP's question.

Comment: Perhaps you could more easily calculate the number of invalid substrings, then subtract it from the number of all substrings.

Comment: How to check is a sub string fits the asked criterion? That's what I'm asking. @AmitKumar

Answer (score 3):

Define `D[i]` - number of valid substrings ending at index `i`.

Assuming you have this `D[i]`, the solution is simply `D[0]+D[1]+...+D[n-1]`.

Calculating `D` is fairly simple, by iterating the string and for each charater:

- if it is "valid", all substrings ending with this characters are valid.
- Otherwise, only by extending a valid substring that ended at last character - makes it valid.

C code:

```
int NumValidSubstrings(char* s) {
  int n = strlen(s);
  int D[n] = {0};  // VLA, if that's an issue, just use dynamic allocation
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
    if (s[i] == 'z' || s[i] == 'a') {
      // if character is valid, each substring ending with it is also valid.
      D[i] += i + 1;
    } else if (i > 0) {
      // Else, only valid substrings from last character, that are extended by 1
      D[i] = D[i-1];
    }
  }
  int count = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) count += D[i];
  return count;
}
```

Notes:

1. This technique is called [Dynamic Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming).
2. This solution is `O(n)` time + space.
3. You can save some space by not storing the entire `D` array - but only the last value and calculate `count` on the fly, making this solution `O(1)` space  and `O(n)` time.

Comment: Just one more doubt @amit. How do we calculate D[0], D[1] - - - - , D[6] in this?